# How to calculate observed frequencies of the cells of a 2x2 table given the totals of rows and columns and the Chi square test p value?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

Does exist a method to calculate back the observed values of a contingency table 2x2 when I have only the p value of the Chi square test and the marginal totals of rows and columns? 
I'm currently extracting data from papers for a systematic review and meta-analysis and a study I wish to include reports only p values of Chi square test for dichotomous variables, and I can find in the article only the values corresponding to rows and columns totals.
Maybe it is a silly question, but by hand I am only able to calculate expected frequencies given the totals, not the observed!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For sufficiently small tables, low totals, and the use of many significant digits in the p-value, this might be possible (because there will be a relatively small, finite number of tables consistent with the marginals and one can compute p-values for them all in searching for a match).  Could you provide the information?

Comment: Hi @whuber thank for your reply! One example of data that I have is: totals of the two rows from top to bottom 130 and 123; total of the columns from left to right 209 and 44; total N=253; p value p=0.4014 In all the cases  I wish to do that the total N is below 300 and I don't have cells with 0. Thanks a lot!

Comment: We need to know *exactly* how this test is being performed.  Using two standard methods (with and without a continuity correction) and employing the chi-squared distribution to compute the p-value, I find that it's impossible to get a p-value to agree with $0.4014$ to any better than the first decimal place, no matter what values might be in the table.  The good news is that if we can find out how the paper does it calculations, it's likely we can identify the entries in the table exactly except when the p-values are extremely small (less than $0.0002$).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Unfortunately the paper does not report any additional information, because it reports in methods only: "Nonparametric analysis was performed using the chi square or Fisher’s exact test, as indicated". Maybe should I contact the authors for raw data

Comment: Fisher's Exact Test is not the chi-squared test, so that's useful additional information.  The $2\times 2$ matrix $\pmatrix{110&20\\99&24}$ has a Fisher Exact Test p-value of $0.4107:$ that's as close as I can get, but it's not quite the reported value.  You might also ask the authors for details on their computational methods, because it looks like their statistical results are otherwise irreproducible.